# Gmail add-on compose trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

We are trying to build an add-on to automatically insert an image when user clicks on 'compose' / 'reply' / 'forward'. Unfortunatelly, we found that the only trigger available is to show a UI which the user then needs to click, and only then the image is inserted.
We need to avoid the extra click, meaning:
User goes to Gmail
User clicks Compose
Result: The compose button triggered the images insertion.

Can anyone of the experts here help me with this innovative trigger?
Thank you!

We tried to use the compose triggers like this, but as expected is showed us an extra button to insert signature, only on click the image is inserted.
We are expecting to click on compose and the images is automatically inserted.

[appscript.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5tgD.png)
[code.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJLeI.png)

Comment: Learn how to post and  [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)